# Bootrec /fixboot/mbr wont work

Tags: fedora

Okay I decided to mess around with fedora 22 and dual installed it with my windows 8.1 laptop (has uefi) and for some reason something went wrong with it. After deleting Linux partition and resizing c:\ I go to fix mbr and boot with recovery, but here is the issue... It won't even work. It's still there as if I didn't do anything, asking me if I want to boot in fedora 22, fedora recovery or windows boot manager.

Answer (score 0):

UEFI booting does not use Master or Partition Boot Records.

UEFI boot entries listed are from NVRAM.

UEFI firmware "setup" should present under "boot options" the functionality to list boot entries, to reorder boot entries, to create new boot entry, to delete boot entry.